# Lambda function typing in Dart?

Tags: dart

Basically, I try to duplicate the way to type functions in Haskell.

```
myIdentity :: a -> a  -- type only
myIdentity = \a -> a
```

In TypeScript, I found we can do like this,

```
type identity = <A>(a: A) => A; // type only
const identity: identity = a => a;
```

In Dart, so far I know we can write as follows

```
var identity = (a) => a;
```

or

```
A identity<A>(A a) => a;
```

Can we also express function type like Haskell/TypeScript style?

**EDIT:**

basically, I want to write separately in 2 lines

1. a type definition alone for a function such as "blueprint" of the function.
2. with the type definition, the actual implementation of the function

**EDIT2:**

```
typedef IdSpecific<T> = T Function(T);
IdSpecific id = (x) => x;

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('Hello world: ${id(5)}!');
  print('Hello world: ${id("Five")}!');
}
```

the result:

```
Hello world: 5!
Hello world: Five!
```

Comment: Can you explain in words exactly what you want for people who aren't fluent with Haskell or TypeScript?  What is wrong with `A identity<A>(A a) => a;`?

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for asking. I added an explanation. Please see my Edit.

Comment: `typedef IdentityFunction<A> = A Function(A);`?

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks! it works, and I self-answered, but the credit is yours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the generic function directly as:

```dart
var identity = <T>(T x) => x;
```

You can give it a type, like in TypeScript, by:

```dart
typedef IdAny = T Function<T>(T);
IdAny identity = <T>(T x) => x;
```

or write the function type directly as:

```dart
T Function<T>(T) identity = <T>(T x) => x;
```

Here the `identity` function is a generic function. You can specialize it as `var intId = identity<int>; var stringId = identity<String>;` if you want to.

Notice that this is *not* the same as:

```dart
typdef IdSpecific<T> = T Function(T);
IdSpecific id2 = (x) => x;
```

In this latter case, the function is not generic. Instead the *type alias* is generic, but it is instantiated (to its bound `dynamic`) when used to type `id2`, which therefore has type `IdSpecific<dynamic>`, aka. `dynamic Function(dynamic)`, and its value is `(dynamic x) => x`.

Comment: So here's the problem. like I've illustrated in my Q. Isn't it possible to make independent <a type definition alone for a function such as "blueprint" of the function> then <with the type definition, the actual implementation of the function> in Dart? That would be problematic to me.

Comment: Please note, this question is not asking how to define the function with type "directly", and it's actually the opposite. Type definition alone (blueprint) the attach the type to the actual implementation. Thanks.

Comment: That's precisely what the second code example does: Defines the type of a generic function from `T` to `T` for any `T`, then defines a variable with that type an assigns a function implementation to it. The `<T>(T x) => x` is how Dart writes a generic function literal.

If you want to write `IdAny<int> intId = (x) => x;` you can do that too. You *cannot* write `IdAny id = (x) => x;` because the *type* is that of a generic function, and the literal is not a generic function.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, actually, I am pretty new on Dart and pretty much confused. Actually, I don't see what's wrong with `typedef IdSpecific<T> = T Function(T);` and have tested in some code. Please review my EDIT2 on my Q. It does work as a generic function as expected. Please give me your thought on this. Thanks again.

Comment: It works as a *general* function of type `dynamic Function(dynamic)`. It works for all objects, but if you do `var x = id(2);`, the type of `x` becomes `dynamic` instead of `int`.
For `T Function<T>(T) id = <T>(T x) => x;`, if you do `var x = id(2);`, the *static type* of `x` becomes `int`. The generic function can adapt to the static type of the argument and have the same type as return type. The `(x) => x` function statically returns `dynamic` for any argument. Neither function is *wrong*, they're just different, but the generic function matches what you had in TypeScript,

Comment: Irn Thanks for the detail!  Actually, I did `final id = ((x) => x) as IdAny;` See my own Answer EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef Identity<A> = A Function(A);
Identity identity = (a) => a;
```

Self answer, but the credit goes to [@jamesddin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin).

Thank you!

EDIT

```
typedef IdAny = T Function<T>(T);
final id = ((x) => x) as IdAny;

final x = id(4);
```

This makes `int x`